# Issue in replace function in R

Tags: r, vector, replace

**I have a vector:**

```
> a <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
```

I am trying to replace the value of everything with that value incremented by 1, like below:

```
a <- (1,2,3,4,5)
> replace(a,a==4,5)
[1] 0 1 2 3 5
```

But when I try to replace 3 with 4, there is some issue

```
replace(a,a==3,4)
[1] 0 1 2 4 4
```

Both 3 and 5 are getting converted to 4.

and again when I try to replace 2 with 3, the same happens

```
> replace(a,a==2,3)
[1] 0 1 3 3 4
```

Can someone point out what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: are you looking for a<-a+1 ??

Comment: @waterling: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` doesn't change its argument.

```
> a = c(0,1,2,3,4)
> replace(a,a==2,99)
[1]  0  1 99  3  4
```

But `a` is still the same:

```
> a
[1] 0 1 2 3 4
```

so when you thought you'd converted the 4 to a 5 in `a` you hadn't. Use the return value if you want to change `a`:

```
> a
[1] 0 1 2 3 4
> a = replace(a,a==2,99)
> a
[1]  0  1 99  3  4
```

[As pointed out in comments, there are better ways to add 1 to all values of a vector, `a=a+1` being the best]